# jQuery updating css state of class instances in a main.js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, methods, instance

I have a main.js file which I am initiating a game with two class instances. Head and Apple. I want to monitor css changes from my main.js file but it is not staying updated on the changes happening in the Head instance, namely, every 500 ms the position of it changes due to changes in its css.  I would like to do certain actions depending on that "head's" positioning and therefore its css. Should I be using a jquery method to monitor this? I am not sure where to go. I have tried accessing the css properties by defining them with `this` in the constructor and also using variables in the main.js file. neither have worked.

main.js

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      const head = new Head($('#board'));
      const apple = new Apple($('#board'));
    
    
        $('body').on('keydown', function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode === 37) {
            console.log('pressed left');
            head.currentDirection = 'left';
          } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
            console.log('pressed right');
            head.currentDirection = 'right';
          } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
            console.log('pressed up');
            head.currentDirection = 'up';
          } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
            console.log('pressed down');
            head.currentDirection =  'down';
          } 
        }); 
    
        let position = head.node.position();
    
        if (position.top === apple.randomTop && position.left === apple.randomLeft) {
          this.endGame();
        }
      });
```

Apple

```
  

    class Apple {
    
      constructor($el) {
        this.node = $('<img id="apple"></img>');
        this.node.attr('src', 'src/assets/apple.jpg');
        $el.append(this.node);
        this.randomTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) * 50
        this.randomLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) * 50
        this.node.css({ top: this.randomTop, left: this.randomLeft });
      }
    }
```

Head

```
    // creates a constructor function - research ES6 classes
    class Head {
    
      // this is what's called when you use the "new" keyword
      constructor($el) {
          this.node = $('<div id="head"></div>');
          this.currentDirection = 'right';
          this.SPEED = 500;
          $el.append(this.node);
          this.node.css({ top: 0, left: 0 });
          this.toBeCleared = setTimeout(this.move.bind(this), this.SPEED);
        
      }
    
      // same as Head.prototype.move = function() {...}
      move() {
          let direction = this.currentDirection;
          let position = this.node.position();
    
          if (position.left === 700 || position.top === 700 || position.left === -50 || position.top === -50) {
            console.log('Game Over');
            this.endGame();
        }
    
          if (direction === 'right') {
            position.left += 50;
          } else if (direction === 'left') {
            position.left -= 50;
          } else if (direction === 'up') {
            position.top -= 50; 
          } else if (direction === 'down') {
            position.top += 50;
          }
    
          this.node.css(position);
          this.toBeCleared = setTimeout(this.move.bind(this), this.SPEED);
      }
    
      endGame() {
          console.log('game has ended')
          // this.node.css(position);
          clearTimeout(toBeCleared);
      }
    
    
    }
```

Comment: You are defining `head` and `apple` inside of your `document.ready` function. This limits the scope of those variables. Try moving them to a global position outside of that.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried what you recommended and when I tried accessing the position of the element using ```let position = head.node.position();
  console.log(position)``` it still didnt show the updates, just the initial position of the 'head'

Comment: Why not store top/left in the class and run the css from those rather than reading them from the css?  This will also nicely keep the separation of concerns for game logic and presentation (as well as being quicker, if that's relevant in your case)

Comment: I messed with it a bit more, and using the global variable did indeed work, not quite how I expected though. Thank you so much.